# java.io.IOException: Too many open files when reading files from folder and subfolders

Tags: java, file, java-11

I'm trying to read files from a folder and its subfolders but after reading certain files, it throws

> java.io.IOException: Too many open files

I am having more than 80k files which I have to read. I am unable to close files. Maybe I am having a wrong approach. 
Please guide me to the right path. Thanks
Here is my Logcat

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.makePipe(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.<init>(EPollSelectorImpl.java:83)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorProvider.openSelector(EPollSelectorProvider.java:36)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:167)
```

**Code**

```
try (Stream<Path> filePathStream=Files.walk(Paths.get(FOLDER_PATH))) {
            filePathStream.forEach(filePath -> {
                if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {

                    System.out.println(filePath.toFile().getAbsoluteFile().toString());
                    try {
                        String content = Files.readString(filePath);
                        System.out.println(filePath.getFileName());
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(content);
                        // System.out.println(file.getName());

                        HashMap yourHashMap1 = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject1.toString(), HashMap.class);
                        request.add(new Config().client().prepareIndex("recipe_json", "default").setSource(yourHashMap1));

                    } catch (IOException ignore) {
                    }
```

Comment: It sounds like it's indeed the wrong approach; that said, this error usually comes from a limitation at the OS level.

Comment: The number of allocated file descriptors cannot exceed the limit that the system can support. To find out the current system limit for file descriptors, run the following command:

`cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max`, assumed *nix

Comment: @MauricePerry @snr I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 and running the above command gives  `1614882`

Comment: how am I supposed to deal with that?

Comment: Please provide more lines of your stack trace.  What is causing `openSelector` to be called?

Comment: You tagged java-8 but `Files.readString()` was introduced in java-11.

Comment: The exception you posted is not thrown by the code you posted. You need to fix that if you don't want to see your question closed. It looks to me like you are leaking sockets, not files. Maybe even Selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of possible reasons for the problem:

- You may simply be opening too many files at the same time.   I don't see how, because `Files.readString(filePath)` *should not leak*.  However, I notice that you are squashing `IOException`, and that might be throwing away some significant evidence.
- You may be opening files ... or pipes or sockets somewhere else.  Maybe here:

  ```
  request.add(new Config().client()
                          .prepareIndex("recipe_json", "default")
                          .setSource(yourHashMap1));
  ```

---

> I am using Elasticsearch Bulk API and adding the content of the file to bulk at this line of code. does that break the rule?

Probably yes.  Check the API documentation.  I expect that you need to "close" or "disconnnect" the client.  If you don't, that is liable to leak sockets.

Comment: I am using `Elasticsearch Bulk API` and adding the content of the file to bulk at this line of code. does that break the rule?

Comment: You're right. It's causing the issue. I've tried after commenting the line and it works fine. But I need that data in this request. How am I supposed to deal with it? Any Idea?

Comment: Try using a single `client` object, rather than creating a new one for for each file you process.

Comment: keeping a single `client` solved the issue. Thanks. I was working over for hours. Thank you so much